# Is there a way to create a number from two others in a way that they can be found afterwards?

Tags: robotics

I have to find a way to send two variables between 1 and 8 between two robots, but the IR function only allows one. Is there a way to make a number out of these two that can be easily transformed back into the original variables ?

For example, if var1=5 and var2=7, I want to be able to make a var3 that is easily transformed back into var1=5 and var2=7 for the robot.

Just for information, the robot I use is a ThymioII, it's documentation can be found there : https://www.thymio.org/en:asebalanguage

Comment: HOw about coding a and b as 10a+b?

Comment: @Juanito I could, but I don't know how to go back from there. If var1=5 and var2=7, var3 would be 57, but how to get back from there in the second robot ? He'd just get var3

Comment: I was hoping the hint would be enough.  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Juanito's suggestion, if you encode like so:

```
c = 10 * a + b
```

Then you can decode like so:

```
a = c / 10
b = c % 10
```

This assumes that the `/` [operator](https://www.thymio.org/en:asebalanguage#toc8) in Aseba is integer division rounding down.

If you prefer to work in binary, you can take advantage of the fact that Aseba integers are $16$ bits wide to encode with shifts:

```
c = (a << 8) + b
```

And decode:

```
a = c >> 8
b = c & 0xff
```

The first scheme will be more convenient if you will need to print out or otherwise debug the values of $c$ in decimal notation, so that $a=5$ and $b=7$ gets encoded as `57`. The second scheme will be more convenient if you'll be viewing values in hexadecimal, so that $a=5$ and $b=7$ gets encoded as `0x0507`.

Comment: I didn't use the binary one, but thank you very much, I didn't think about using the % operator !